# Efficient way of comparing data from two different data sources (MySQL and Hadoop)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have data coming from MySQL like so..

```
ItemID
Metric1
Metric2
Metric3
```

and data like so I use Hive to pull off Hadoop..

```
ItemID
Metric1 
Metric2
Metric3
```

Now the ItemID is the unique identifier.  So what I'd to output into one file with the following column setup is:

```
ItemID
Metric1 (MySQL)
Metric2 (MySQL)
Metric3 (MySQL)
Metric1 (Hadoop)
Metric2 (Hadoop)
Metric3 (Hadoop)
```

Is there another way of doing it then just looping through one file and then searching for the ItemID in the other file and outputting the matched rows into another file?  This seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is your lucky day, because Hadoop is built for grouping. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a natural way to get Hive to do this in SQL because it has to do with denormalized data. The only annoying part is your data format, but I'll get into that later.

My suggestion is write a MapReduce job that loads both data sets, groups by the unique item ID value, then collates them in the reducer.

Some pseudocode:

```
mapper for MySQL:
  output ItemID as the key, Metric# + "(MySQL)" as the value
mapper for Hadoop:
  output ItemID as the key, Metric# + "(Hadoop)" as the value
reducer:
  output the ItemID, then each item in the iterator
```

Some notes:

- I suggest using [`MultipleInputs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) so you can differentiate between whether the data came from Hadoop or MySQL. You'll set up one map class for each, then assign that map class to the input data.
- It looks like your input format is a bit of a painful format since the "record delimiter" is a bit ambiguous. How do you tell that you reach the end of an ItemID and into the next ItemID? Are they significantly different from Metrics? You may need some sort of custom inputformat or record reader to get this done. If you could change your input data somehow so it would read in `ItemID\tMetric1;Metric2;Metric3` your life would be a lot easier.

---

You could consider Pig for this. It deals with denormalized data in the form you have a bit better with its "bags". You could use the [`COGROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#COGROUP) operator after two separate `LOAD` statements to group the data together, then spit it out. Your input data format would be annoying for pig as well.